# CloudFormation error: Template error: Unable to get mapping for AWSAMIRegionMap::me-south-1::WS2012R2

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I am totally new Cloudformation world, I am trying to run the Cloudformation template (tableau-single-server-master.template) available here:
https://aws-quickstart.s3.amazonaws.com/quickstart-tableau-server/templates/tableau-single-server-master.template
Once I change the region to Bahrain (me-south-1) and run it, I get the error:Unable to get mapping for AWSAMIRegionMap::me-south-1::WS2012R2
notice that the template is based on Oregon. Also when I validate the template before running it, I got the error: Template contains errors.: Template error: every Fn::GetAtt object requires two non-empty parameters, the resource name and the resource attribute 
Please help me sorting this out.

Comment: recommend opening an issue here: https://github.com/aws-quickstart/quickstart-tableau-server/issues/new

Comment: Also counter check your mappings and where they are being reference to ensure that  spellings for the mappings match those in reference section.